# Microsoft Cognitive Services Web Search API - DeSerialization Issues

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services

I want to learn Cognitive Services Web Search APIs so I started creating a bot application  . I already have a account sub- key and other required information also I read many articles and watch build 2016 videos on this as well.I am having trouble while deserializing the result . 
I am not able to find the proxy class that I can use to do that .
The url I am using is https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search/
and I found a proxy class for previous api version . Can anybody tell me how to get proxy class of the  api request / response  in VS 2015 for these service.

My Code look like this:

```
  string BingSearchUrl =  "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search/";
   const string bingKey = "Key";

    public static  async Task<string> Search(string query)
    {
        var client = HttpClientFactory.Create();
        var queryString = BingSearchUrl + "?q=" + query + "&count=10";        
        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", bingKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        // Request parameters
        string r = await client.GetStringAsync(queryString);
        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bing.ExpandableSearchResult>(r);

        return jsonResult.Web.First().Title;
```

Comment: the service return the results  but when I DeserializeObject it showing me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this model, I am able to get the desired result. The Model which is presented in the other answer is not working in my case.

```
namespace BingSearchBot
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public WebPages webPages { get; set; }
        public RelatedSearches relatedSearches { get; set; }
        public RankingResponse rankingResponse { get; set; }
    }
    public class WebPages
    {
        public string webSearchUrl { get; set; }
        public int totalEstimatedMatches { get; set; }
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Value
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public List<About> about { get; set; }
        public string displayUrl { get; set; }
        public string snippet { get; set; }
        public List<DeepLink> deepLinks { get; set; }
        public string dateLastCrawled { get; set; }
        public List<SearchTag> searchTags { get; set; }
    }
    public class About
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeepLink
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string snippet { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchTag
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }
    public class Value2
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string displayText { get; set; }
        public string webSearchUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelatedSearches
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Value2> value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value3
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string answerType { get; set; }
        public int resultIndex { get; set; }
        public Value3 value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mainline
    {
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }

    public class RankingResponse
    {
        public Mainline mainline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
  public string BingSearchUrl = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search/";
        const string bingKey =[KEY];

        public async void Search()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", bingKey);

            // Request parameters
            queryString["q"] = "microsoft";
            queryString["count"] = "10";
            queryString["offset"] = "0";
            queryString["mkt"] = "en-us";
            queryString["safeSearch"] = "Moderate";
            var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?" + queryString;

            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BingJson>(response);

            string title = jsonResult.value[0].name.ToString();

        }
```

With the `jsonResult.value[0]` you can loop through the results. First results is at `[0]` position.

I Created a model class looking at the bing search response `json`. It looks like,

```
 public class BingJson
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public Instrumentation instrumentation { get; set; }
        public string readLink { get; set; }
        public int totalEstimatedMatches { get; set; }
        public Value[] value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Instrumentation
    {
        public string pingUrlBase { get; set; }
        public string pageLoadPingUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string urlPingSuffix { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public About[] about { get; set; }
        public Provider[] provider { get; set; }
        public DateTime datePublished { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    }

    public class Thumbnail
    {
        public string contentUrl { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class About
    {
        public string readLink { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Provider
    {
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That also didn't helped same result . Also my question is about how to download the proxy class of this web api service . I looked for previous version of Bing Search we can add it as a Service Reference in our project but with this new URL I cannot add it as service reference nor I can get the WSDL. I tried it with the previous version of proxy but that also did not helped me. Its very strange that in all the documentation for Web search no where it is mentioned how to get web result.

Comment: Finally after many tries this I created a model which is working fine the problem with your model @codelahiru is it contains a Array properties which due to some reason not getting deserialized .